# Prove an analytic function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\bar{D}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function that is analytic in $D$. Assume that $f$ maps the unit circle $T$ into $T-\{-1\}$. Can we say $f$ is constant?

Here $D$ denotes the unit disc. Who can give some hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** How often does $f(T)$ wind around $f(0)$?

Comment: I know now, use argument principle we got f never vanish inside D, then the maximum principle tell f is constant. Thanks.